# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded trackForMutations.js

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, react-redux

I'm building tree view using d3 visualizations where user can add or remove the nodes from the tree. To build the tree, data is passed in JSON format. I'm updating the JSON object and saving the new values in the store. But after saving I'm getting "Maximum calls stack size exceeded" error.

Please suggest me how to fix this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: not enough data put your codes

Answer (score 0):

That sometimes happens when using slightly bigger JSON files than usual. Try setting the [user limit](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) to something higher than the default and you should be fine:

```
ulimit -n 4096
```